# set to NOT connect to specific nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

There is on nexus repository which my application always connects in the building process. I don't find where this repository is set so:

is it possible to set in the `pom.xml` that do not connect to a specific repository?

Answer (score 0):

`settings.xml` file is the correct location to configure this.

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I want to NOT connect to specific `URL` where I set this in your example?

Comment: Why? You need to have a specific URL in your settings which defines where to download all artifacts?

Comment: I have this, but some where there is an repository which is slowing down the build process. Not sure where is set, so I wanted to blocked it

Comment: So best is to use a repository manager and configure the repositories there...and afterwards you only use the repository manager which is usually in your local network which is magnitudes faster than any other repository from outside...So no such kind problem anymore...

Comment: So what exactly is your problem ? The connection to your nexus ?

Comment: no, that there is a repository which mvn tries to connect to. This repo is always offline, then waits till the the timeout. This takes long for each module.

Comment: You have configured a repository which is always offline? Than just remove it from your settings.xml or worse from your pom file...get the dependencies from somewhere else ...If you configure maven as suggested above Maven will only try to connect to Nexus...

Comment: No. I didn't configure it. Not sure where is configured. Defiantly, it is not configured in my settings.xml or my pom.xml. This is way I wan to explicitly block it, because I do not now why is call in the first place. I think is in a parent pom somewhere